# Dynamic proxy for class

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-remoting, dynamic-proxy, emit

I have a simple class:

```
public class Some
{
 [F("some text")]
 public void Foo()
 {
   //Do something
 }
}
```

External code use my class by calling Foo method. It's search an attribute F, creates an instance of the Some class and then calls Foo method. 
Now I want that Foo method will be executed on the remote machine. How to solve?
First solution is to use .net remoting tehnology, but its require special creation of the instance which I cant change. Another solution is rewrite my Foo method and call a web service method inside it, but I have a lot of methods and sometimes I need to run it localy. 
Third solution is to use something like Post sharp, but it's seems too complex.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: Does this class reside in a DLL? Would sharing that DLL with the remote application be an option? So that the other application simply refrerences your DLL?

Comment: No its not a dll, unfortunately. And the is no possibility to place it in a dll...